# How to get "stream information" for Sony AVR using Sony Control API?

Tags: sony-audio-control-api

I am using Sony STR-DN1080 together with the [Sony Audio Control API](https://developer.sony.com/develop/audio-control-api/api-references/api-overview-2). Everything is working fine, except that I cannot find how to fetch the "stream information" of the currently playing stream. (The one that shows the audio codec of the currently playing stream using the display button on the front panel, e.g. "Dolby Atmos - Linear PCM DAtmos").

Comment: What is the source you using (eg input source): casting (like spotify) or dlna (network) or bluetooth ... ?

Comment: Cables box and computer using HDMI ports

Comment: Hi David, can you please comment if such information is available using the API?

Comment: I have looked in the API and it seems that this is not possible unfortunately. I wanted to know what codec/container/bitrate, etc, was being decoded, regardless of the input (but typically the HDMI and/or optical inputs), but alas not possible.